# How to return multiple results through runTest method in Java request sampler for JMeter?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

Hi guys I am relatively new to Jmeter and I had a question regarding overriding the runTest method in custom java request sampler. I want to get saparate time durations for all the transactions in my logic but all I can see is just one single duration between result.sampleStart() and result.sampleEnd() methods as the method can return only one single result. Any friends out here have got any suggestions as to how to get separate time durations? Here's my code for custom Java sampler :

```
package JMeterClient;


import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;



public class JMeterSample extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

/*  @Override    public Arguments getDefaultParameters() { 
    Arguments defaultParameters = new Arguments();
    defaultParameters.addArgument("", ""); 
    defaultParameters.addArgument("", "");
    defaultParameters.addArgument("", "");
    return defaultParameters;     } */

    @Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
         SampleResult result = new SampleResult();

         boolean success = true;

         result.sampleStart();

         SampleMethods methods= new SampleMethods();
         result.sampleStart();
         methods.randomNumberGenerator();
         result.sampleEnd();
         result.getEndTime();
         methods.reverseString();
         methods.run();

         result.sampleEnd();

         result.setSuccessful(success);

         return result;


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you trying to build a result tree where you will be having one parent sample and a number of sub-samples. If so, according to [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide you should look into the following method:

[SampleResult.addSubResult()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult%28org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult%29)

as per description,

> **addSubResult**
>
> *public void* **addSubResult**(SampleResult subResult)
>
> Add a subresult and adjust the parent byte count and end-time.
>
> Parameters: *subResult* -

Comment: Hey Dmitri, for the same scenario I can see the result but I'm getting an error when I see the Jmeter log as follows:-              ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
 at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setEndTime(SampleResult.java:962)
 at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.addSubResult(SampleResult.java:559)                                              Any idea what this means?